# Oracle statistics like STATS_MODE avoiding the default behavior extending to another column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Query to extract the most popular hour from a list of dates.

Table:
id 
parent_id
started
duration

```
select STATS_MODE(extract(HOUR from started)) as most_pop_call_start, 
       avg(duration) as avg_duration 
from table where parent_id = 'xxx';
```

This works pretty fine but in case we have records with the same extract(hour) the STATS_MODE will take the minimum value as per default.

Instead in the edge case where there isn't unique result I'd like to extend the filter using also the duration.

E.g.

```
| **ID** | **PARENT_ID** | **STARTED** | **DURATION** |
| test_01 | P_1 | 2017-01-12 10:21:53.000000 | 32 |
| test_02 | P_1 | 2017-01-12 10:22:53.000000 | 50 |
| test_03 | P_1 | 2017-01-12 11:23:53.000000 | 19 |
| test_04 | P_1 | 2017-01-12 11:24:53.000000 | 39 |
| test_05 | P_1 | 2017-01-12 12:25:53.000000 | 49 |
| test_06 | P_1 | 2017-01-12 12:26:53.000000 | 59 |
| test_07 | P_1 | 2017-01-12 13:27:53.000000 | 69 |
| test_08 | P_1 | 2017-01-12 13:28:53.000000 | 79 |
| test_09 | P_1 | 2017-01-12 14:29:53.000000 | 98 |
| test_10 | P_1 | 2017-01-12 15:30:53.000000 | 99 |
```

In this scenario I'd like to have as most_pop_call_start value '13' because the max count(*) group by extract(HOUR) return 2 and more then 1 set of records have 2 as count so I'll evaluate the duration column taking 79 as max of the sub-set (10, 11, 12, 13).

Comment: Hey, what is going on here? Another person posted almost exactly the same question today. Are you guys taking an exam right now or something?

Comment: Hi @mathguy actually even before creating the thread here I asked Sameer to help me out. I didn't know he was going to ask in here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select min( hr ) keep ( dense_rank last order by cnt,max_duration ) as most_pop_call_start, 
       sum( duration ) / sum( cnt ) as avg_duration 
from (
    select extract(HOUR from started) as hr,
           count(*)  as cnt,
           sum( duration ) as duration,
           max( duration )  as max_duration
    from table
    where parent_id = 'xxx'
    group by extract(HOUR from started)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved starting from the krokodilko proposal.

This's the whole query:

```
SELECT tp.d_id , u.email , ta.email_subject AS headline , ta.start_date , ta.closing_date , tp.call_cost , SUM(tpc.duration) AS duration , COUNT(tpc.id) AS call_count , ta.currency
  , ( SELECT MIN(hr) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY cnt, max_duration, l_id ) AS most_pop_call_start FROM (
        SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM started) AS hr, count(*) AS cnt , SUM(duration) AS duration , MAX(duration) AS max_duration , phone_number_id AS l_id FROM table_phone_call GROUP BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM started), phone_number_id
      ) where l_id = tpc.phone_number_id
    ) AS most_pop_call_start
  --, STATS_MODE(extract(HOUR from tpc.started)) AS most_pop_call_start
  , AVG(tpc.duration) AS avg_duration
  , tb.name AS business_name
FROM table_a ta
  JOIN table_phone tp ON ta.id = tp.d_id
  JOIN table_phone_call tpc ON tp.phone_id = tpc.phone_number_id
  JOIN table_b tb ON ta.business_id = tb.id
  JOIN users u ON tb.id = u.business_id
WHERE phone_id IS NOT NULL
      AND TRUNC(ta.closing_date) = to_date('#{jobParameters['dateCriteria']}', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
GROUP BY tp.d_id , ta.email_subject , ta.start_date , ta.closing_date , tp.call_cost , tpc.phone_number_id , u.email , ta.currency , tb.name
```

Many thanks